# Java reading an argument from terminal

Tags: java

I'm trying to implement the following:

```
 public class Main {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
    //READ FILE IN
         String filename = args[0];
         System.out.println(filename);
      }}
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to run `java br/com/seimos/minijava/Main.java < a` or `java br/com/seimos/minijava/Main.java a` for example, I get an error.  Why?? (by the way, I need to get it so that I can do `java br/xx/xx.../xx`.

Thanks!

EDIT: Sorry, I typed it wrong initially.  I DID run `java` not `javac`.

The error I get is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: br/com/seimos/minijava/Main/java
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.seimos.minijava.Main.java
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: For running, use command java instead javac and put the class name, not the java file --> java br.com.seimos.minijava.Main if your package is br.com.seimos.minijava

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass arguments at **compile-time**, but at **runtime**.

```
javac --> compiles your Java program
java --> runs the generated bytecode
```

---

```
java br/com/seimos/minijava/Main.java -args
                                   ^ remove (.java)
```

Java runtime runs the **.class** bytecode-generated, which is of the name supplied, not the uncompiled `.java` source

Comment: It was a typo! I typed `java` in the actual thing.  Sorry about that

Comment: Thanks....I can't believe it was that.  I'm sorry....have been coding all night, I didn't catch that.

Answer (score 0):

Running a Java program is a two step process. First the `.java` file is compiled into `.class` files. Then you use the `java` command to execute the class files. Runtime arguments must obviously be passed at runtime when you invoke `java`.

Comment: Sorry about that.  It was a typo.  I typed `java` in the actual thing

Answer (score 0):

For compiling, if the java file is with some package, you need to apply such as br.com.xxx.main.java. If that is just path to the java file that is ok. can you post the error?

Comment: I typed `java` in the actual thing